# Is it appropriate to only use Azure Network Security Groups in production, rather than a standalone firewall?

Tags: azure

Is there any reason not to rely solely on Azure Network Security Groups to secure a production system? I know this is a generalised question and there will always be cases where full fledged/expensive firewalls are required, but for a general purpose application are NSGs secure enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the VMs are solely on Azure VNET, NSG would do pretty much every thing you need to secure your app/VM. You can collect NSG logs to see which traffic were allowed or denied via particular NSG. You can store those logs to any storage account at a minimal cost or Publis it to OMS where you can create a dashboard and have a graphical sense of what is flowing through the NSG.
But there are features like WAF, IPS which are not available on NSG and for that you have to rely on firewall.